# Can I use Telerik Metro Controls Beta in a production app?

Tags: telerik, wpf-controls, custom-controls, microsoft-metro, beta

So far they're the only people I can find that are doing a chart control...

What happens when the beta expires?  How does it expire?  (Does it expire?).  They look great but there is no pricing information or expiry information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direct quote from the EULA:

“You **may distribute** the Programs **as embedded in Your Integrated Products to Your end-users** only pursuant to an end-user license that meets the requirements of this Section.”

So, yes, you can ship Apps built with Telerik Windows 8 Controls Beta to the Store.

Comment: Also, the beta will not expire and its functionality will not change. You will not be forced to buy the controls when a final release is shipped unless you want to use the new features and controls that will be available in the future.

Answer (score -1):

"Beta," by definition, suggests not ready for production use.

There are at least a couple of things you should think about before moving forward:

1. Does the license agreement for the controls allow use in a production app (you did read the license, right?)
2. Are you willing to risk the possibility that the app might suddenly stop working for any and all users who have downloaded it, until such time as you replace the controls with working versions (and get the updated version of your app submitted to the store)?

As long as the controls fit the Windows 8 app design, and don't cause performance or crashing issues, they may not have any impact on whether or not the app gets through certification.

But the larger issue is one of risk. Betas are for testing. IMO, unless the beta includes a "go-live" license, you should probably stick with using beta software for evaluation and testing only.

To be clear, that's no knock on Telerik's beta quality (or anyone else's, for that matter). Just a reminder that beta software isn't finished yet.

Comment: Yes, I have read the EULA and it doesn't answer the questions I've asked, above.  I've marked your post down as it offers no useful information.

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't find my advice useful. If I may suggest, if you want detailed information on Telerik's controls, you might try http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx, or you could try calling one of the several phone numbers listed at the bottom of their website. Either of those would probably get you more specific answers.